# Recurrence doesn't work together with maximize

Tags: recursion

When I'm trying to use a recurrence relation involving maximize it simply fails to compute anything...

```
T[m_, n_] := 1 + Maximize[{T[k, l] + T[k, n - 1 - l] + T[m - 1 - k, l] + 
                         T[m - 1 - k, n - 1 - l], 0 <= k <= m - 1, 0 <= l <= n - 1}, {k,l}, Integers]

T[m_,0]:=0, T[0,n_]:=0
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: The value of T[m,n] depends only on the values of T[i,j] for 0<=i<m, 0<=j<n so manually (if you have a free year or so) you could fill the table of values very slowly :P

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem... If you calculate them by that order: T[0,0],T[0,1],T[1,0],T[1,1],... then everything is easy

Comment: Oh, I didn't mention it in the question (I'll edit it) but I also had stopping conditions T[m_,0]:=0, T[0,n_]:=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
T[m_, n_] := 1 + Max@Table[T[k, l] + T[k, n - 1 - l] + T[m - 1 - k, l] + T[m - 1 - k, n - 1 - l], 
                          {k, 0, m - 1}, {l, 0, n - 1}]
T[m_, 0] := 0
T[0, n_] := 0

Table[T[i, j], {i, 0, 5}, {j, 0, 5}] // Grid
```

$\begin{array}{cccccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
 0 & 1 & 3 & 5 & 5 & 5 \\
 0 & 1 & 3 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
 0 & 1 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 9 \\
\end{array}$